# How to know if Dialog is open?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can i check inside my Angular Components, if the Material Dialog is opened or not? There seems to be no field open for example on MatDialogRef and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The MatDialog service itself tracks which dialogs are open. You can use the MatDialog service property openDialogs to get an array of MatDialogRefs that are open.

See: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialog

Comment: It's a little more direct to use the getDialogByID function rather than getting an array of dialogRefs and checking to see if your dialog is present.